# Convergence of the Fourier series!

Tags: solution-verification, fourier-series

Given $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1,&-2<x<0\\ x,&0<x<2\end{cases}.$$ I want to check that whether the Fourier series converges to $f(x)$.

I have found the Fourier series of this function:

**$$f(x)=1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2}{n^2\pi^2}\left((-1)^n-1\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{2}\right)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{\pi n}(-1)^{n+1}\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{2}\right)$$**

Now we check whether this series converges to $f(x)$ for the intervals $-2<x<0$ and $0<x<2$ .

This function has a jump discontinuity at $x=0$
because
$f(0^{+})\neq f(0^{-})$
and note that on the intervals $-2<x<0$ and $0<x<2$
both the function and its derivative are continuous. Therefore it is a piecewise smooth function. Note that the function itself is not continuous at $x=0$
but because this point of discontinuity is a jump discontinuity the function is still piecewise smooth.

In the intervals $-2<x<0$ and $0<x<2$
the function and hence the periodic extension are both continuous and so on these two intervals the Fourier series will converge to the periodic extension and hence will converge to the function itself.

**Edit:** At the point $x=0$
the function has a jump discontinuity and so the periodic extension will also have a jump discontinuity at this point. That means that at $x=0$
the Fourier series will converge to,

$$\frac{1}{2}\left[f(0^+)+f(0^-)\right]=\frac{1}{2}$$

At the end point $x=2$, $f(x)$ has jump discontinuity. So the Fourier series converges to

$$\frac{1}{2}\left[f(2^+)+f(2^-)\right]=\frac{3}{2}$$

Hence the Fourier seris converges to $f(x)$.

Is it correct?

Please verify someone!

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. By your function continuous on (-2, 0) and (0, 2).

Comment: on what domain is your function periodic?

Comment: "There are many known sufficient conditions for the Fourier series of a function to converge at a given point x, for example if the function is differentiable at x. Even a jump discontinuity does not pose a problem: if the function has left and right derivatives at x, then the Fourier series converges to the average of the left and right limits" - Wikipedia

Comment: @Farmer Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Exodd But in this case Fourier series converges to $f(\frac{1}{2})$, now, can we say that the series converges to $f(x)$?.

Comment: @Farmer I would like to know one more thing. Is it necessary to find the Fourier series because with the help of this condition without determining the Fourier series we can say that whether the Fourier series converges to $f(x)$?

Comment: You would have to add $f(0)=\frac12$ and $f(2)=\frac32$ to get a completely defined function. The second jump is completely missing from your discussion.

Comment: Yes, we can.

Theorem: If $f$ defined in whole $\mathbb{R}$, periodicity with period $2\pi$ and piecewise smooth in any finite interval then the Fourier series $S(x)$ of $f$ converge at every point $x_0$ and $S(x_0)= \frac{f(x_0+0)+f(x_0-0)}{2}$. Particularly, if $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ then $S(x_0)=f(x_0)$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks! I have edited. Can you please see my solution?

Comment: When you say "the Fourier series converges to", then you need a target value from the start. Else the undefined points can have any value in the periodic continuation and you only need to discuss convergence on the actual domain of $f$., which excludes the jump points.

Comment: @LutzLehmann So we don't need to check the convergence at the point of jump disconinuity. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. In principle. Depending on how nitpicky your tutor is, and how much nitpickery they tolerate.